# Dealing with a weak remote

Tags: infrared, remote-control

I've got these LED candles with a remote:

[image]

I've owned a few different models of LED candles in the past, and these ones are the best so far. They have a great-looking, strong light, and realistic flame movement. They come with a remote for turning them on and off.

The problem is... The remote is underpowered. I have four of these candles (the two that aren't in the picture are on a different shelf) and I often have to get out of my bed and get closer to each shelf when I press the buttons on the remote, otherwise the candles don't register them. Getting out of bed is one of my least favorite activities.

Is there some kind of hack for increasing the strength of the remote? If there was a product that I could attach to the end of the remote that took the signal and amplified it, I'd buy that. Or over-voltage the remote? Any other ideas?

Comment: Suggesting what to buy would be off topic, but universal remotes that can learn your existing remote do exist, as well as infrared repeaters. You could also replicate the transmissions with Arduino or something to build your own remote.

Comment: Good idea. Got a recommended model?

Comment: I already said recommending what to buy would be off topic, and there might be reasons why one model would work with your devices while another doesn't, as we have no idea the exact details of what infrared protocol your devices use.

Comment: *Or over-voltage the remote?* If you want to destroy the remote then that would be the way to do it. Look for a product that lets you extend your remote. There used to be these devices that let you control the VCR in the living room from your bedroom. Have you tried bouncing the remote's signal off the ceiling?

Comment: Is it a radio remote or IR?

Comment: My guess is IR but the remote doesn't say.

Comment: If it doesnt have a FCC ID on it it's not RF. The RF ones do use the top led as an indicator tho.

Comment: The metal frame you have the candles sitting on may block an RF (bluetooth?) signal. Try a test - move them to a non-metallic surface and see if the range improves.

Answer (score 0):

Connect a battery pack with 2x AA or AAA. AA have less resistance than a coin cell (Cr2032 it most likely uses). Hence the voltage will not drop down when the IR led gets powered.

Use an IR repeater. You can get the commercial ones, or you can make your own. Theres a couple of projects involving esp8266 so you could control multiple in multiple rooms. Neat and cheap. You could also ditch the remote with this and control them via a website/smartphone app.

Use a universal learning remote. Or see of someone has figured out the standard and found which existing configuration for a JP1 remote or something.